# How to define local variable in Buildroot which is an execution result of bash script

Tags: linux, bash, embedded, cross-compiling, buildroot

There's a local variable in `netmap/LINUX/configure` named `BUILDDIR` and its value is `BUILDDIR=$PWD`.It should have to be redirected to `$(@D)` which is netmap package build directory, `/usr/local/buildroot/output/build/netmap-master` in my case;otherwise, object files will be outputed to `buildroot` root directory.

I created a variable named `NETMAP_CURRENT_BUILD` and let it be `/usr/local/buildroot/output/build/netmap-master`,`$(@D)`, 
and then I wanna replace `BUILDDIR=$PWD` to 
`BUILDDIR=/usr/local/buildroot/output/build/netmap-master`. By using sample code as following, it can't be done.

Sample Code :(`sed` part worked fine at terminal console)

```
    define NETMAP_BUILD_CMDS
    NETMAP_CURRENT_DIR = $(sed -e 's/\//\\\//g' <<< "$(@D)")   --   empty
    echo "$$(sed -e 's/\//\\\//g' <<< "$(@D)")"               -- this line works fine
...
    sed -e 's/BUILDDIR=$$PWD/BUILDDIR=$(NETMAP_CURRENT_DIR)/g' -i $(@D)/LINUX/configure     
(double $$PWD, it has to be like this, which means string $PWD is needed rather than its value.)
    ...
        endef
```

Comment: If the variable contains slashes, don't use slash as the delimiter. I don't think you can expect the subshell to know what `"$(@D)"` means but if it works in the command you run between the `...` then try `sed "s%BUILDDIR=$$PWD%BUILDDIR=$(@D)%" $(@D)/LINUX/configure`

Comment: If `$$PWD` contains slashes (like it usually would) then in your current approach, you'd need to escape those slashes, too. In the preceding comment, switching to a syntax where the slashes don't need to be escaped works around that, too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, tripleee! My host machine is on Gentoo text mode console, so I'm unable to paste my `netmap.mk` , sorry for that. The subshell is actually inside of the `netmap.mk` , so in this block, shell script is able to be executed. Due to Buildroot syntax, if I wanna have string `$PWD` in my expression, it has to be `$$PWD`.

Comment: That's why I'm thinking general `makefile` syntax would work here, but I'm not familiar with this part of the Linux source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need this, see below. However, if you do need the result of a shell command in a `make` variable, use `$(shell ...)`

Since this is a makefile, the $ are interpreted by `make`, not by the shell. Therefore, `make` will try to evaluate `sed -e 's/\//\\\//g' <<< "$(@D)"` as a variable name. There is of course no variable with that name, so you get an empty string.

To let make run a shell command and store the result in a make variable, use the $(shell ...) function. So

```
NETMAP_CURRENT_DIR = $(shell sed -e 's/\//\\\//g' <<< "$(@D)")
```

Note that that should be done *outside* of the `NETMAP_BUILD_CMDS`, because the contents of `NETMAP_BUILD_CMDS` is in fact a shell script: `make` first expands all variables in that script, then passes it to the shell line-by-line. The shell will actually error out on the above statement because you have spaces around the `=` so `NETMAP_CURRENT_DIR` is interpreted as a command name.

If you want to store the result in a shell variable rather than a `make` variable, then the easiest solution is to use backticks `` `...` `` to delimit the command instead of `$(...)`:

```
define NETMAP_BUILD_CMDS
        NETMAP_CURRENT_DIR=`sed -e 's/\//\\\//g' <<< "$(@D)"`; \
        sed -e 's/BUILDDIR=$$PWD/BUILDDIR=$$NETMAP_CURRENT_DIR/g' -i $(@D)/LINUX/configure
endef
```

**However, in your case you don't need this at all.**

First of all, you can do simple substitutions directly in `make`.

```
NETMAP_CURRENT_DIR = $(subst /,\/,$(@D))
```

Even better, you can simply use a different delimiter than `/` in your `sed` expression, then there is no need to quote it:

```
sed -e 's@BUILDDIR=$$PWD@BUILDDIR=$(@D)@g' -i $(@D)/LINUX/configure
```

One final note: modifications to the code like this are better done in `NETMAP_POST_PATCH_HOOKS` than in `NETMAP_BUILD_CMDS`. So finally, the best solution is:

```
define NETMAP_FIX_BUILDDIR
        sed -e 's@BUILDDIR=$$PWD@BUILDDIR=$(@D)@g' -i $(@D)/LINUX/configure
endef
NETMAP_POST_PATCH_HOOKS += NETMAP_FIX_BUILDDIR
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I used configure patches instead. Netmap is a great package, but its configure isn't for all purposes such as cross compiling.